# Binary powershell module command formatting

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module

I'm writing a binary powershell module that will replace another command line tool that just outputs text.

I have a handful of commands that follow the powershell verb guide (eg. `Add-MyModuleUser -UserName "My Username"`) but I would like to also have an overloaded command that takes the object responses of these and format them like the tool I'm replacing which accepts input in the following format:

```
myModule addUserName "My Username"
```

My instinct says to have a command called `Invoke-MyModule` with an alias to `myModule`, so I could call `Invoke-MyModule addUserName "My Username"` which would call `Add-MyModuleUser` and format that output with like the original tool.

Question: How can I get a powershell command to accept input like this?

Note: I was reading about ParameterSets which seem promising, I was thinking I could declare the parameter set to string, so the first word in the string sets the ParameterSet for the rest of the parameters that are entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the remaining parameters are based on the value of a parameter rather than the presence of a parameter, you probably need to use "Dynamic Parameters".  See "get-help [about_functions_advanced_parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)", and the dynamic parameter content is towards the end.

Parametersets would be fine if you used a series of switch parameters (-AddUserName, for example) rather than the value "addUserName".  ParameterSets are chosen by the presence of parameters that are exclusive to a particular set.